# In pascal, can I call a procedure with a function as parameter?

Tags: delphi, pascal

```
empty(game, left(actualPos));
```

empty is the procedure that has 2 parameters and I want to call a function (left) as the second parameter. Is that possible in Pascal?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is possible and since I am not an expert on Pascal I will not post an unqualified answer. Answering those type of questions which can be solved with a minute of research on the internet does not add to the quality of the community anyway.

Comment: Can you show us the left function? how you pass the param?

Comment: What you've written looks like you're actually passing the return value of `left` and not the function itself.  You can pass a reference to a function as a parameter but, in this case, that doesn't look to be what you want.  The code you've written should compile if the types are compatible.  Does it?

Comment: You could try to look for references to functions (= anonymous methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the type of the second parameter to `empty()` is of the same type as the return value of `left()` (or the value of `left()` can be autoconverted/promoted to the type of the second parameter of `empty()`), *and* the second parameter is not pass-by-reference (usually declared as `var`), then you can call `empty()` as you have shown above.

If both of the constraints are not true, then the call will generate an error, possibly at compile time.

Comment: If `actualPos` is a variable so he can use the function even he pass the `param` as `var` or `const`

Comment: The question is not whether `actualPos` is a variable or constant, the question is whether `empty(a; b)` is declared as `empty(a; b)` or `empty(a; var b)` - in the latter case, you cannot pass a function return (`left(...)`) as `b` because `empty()` is presumed to be trying to _alter_ the value of `b`.

Comment: Thank you! I was passing it by reference

Answer (score 0):

What I understood in the question is something like this. I've took the liberty of guessing wildly about the details and leaving things out, but the code should speak for itself (and be valid Delphi syntax):

```
type
  TGameData=class
    //add more fields here
  end;
  TGamePosition=record
    //add more fields here
  end;
  TSomeGamePosFunc=function(gd:TGameData;gp:TGamePosition): boolean;

  function Left(game:TGameData;APos:TGamePosition): boolean;
  begin
    //if something with the values in the fields of APos then
    Result:=true;
    //else Result:=false;
  end;

  procedure Empty(game:TGameData;something:TSomeGamePosFunc);
  var
    p:TGamePosition;
  begin
    //initialize game
    //for p.x:=0 to width of field
    //for p.y:=0 to height of field?
    //if
    something(game,p);
    //then...
  end;
```